# Command "Dig" Not Work

Tags: command-line, dns

i have this problem.

The command `dig +trace gnu` only return this:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu <<>> +trace gnu.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Received 28 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) in 0 ms
```

But i want all the trace. Why is this?

Comment: It's the same here. either locolhost or my router dns. But if I specify `@1.1.1.1` or `@8.8.8.8` it works. might be related to something about local dns

Comment: It is related to your local DNS, probably `dnsmasq`. The command works for me, giving me ~50 lines of output.

Answer (score 2):

Took me a bit of digging to find out what is going on here.  Basically, the new systemd nonsense has forced itself into the DNS space.  If you read `/etc/resolv.conf`, you'll see it refers to `systemd-resolved`.  You'll also see your `nameserver` entry is `127.0.0.53`.

```
netstat -pntul | grep :53 show:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29133/named         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27505/systemd-resol
```

But systemd-resolved passes queries NOT to your bind9 server, but to glibc.  Unfortunately, glibc isn't a resolver.  It will pass queries, but does so in a way that breaks `+trace`.  `+notrace` works just fine.

To get around this, I removed `resolvconf`, turned off systemd-resolved, and changed the `/etc/resolv.conf` entry from `127.0.0.53` to `127.0.0.1`.

Before you make the change, you can `dig @127.0.0.1 +trace google.com` and see that `dig +trace` works as expected proving the systemd implementation is broken and should be removed.